# How to create custom UI for a MATLAB application?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

MATLAB possesses all features I need in my application, except for one - a 21st century look to the applications it builds. The old UI controls with the skin from the 90s just don't cut it anymore. Are there ways to customize the GUI of the compiled window itself? I know of App Designer for MATLAB (which is an alternative for GUIDE as I understood) but that's not close enough. For example, I want a complete flat design look with sprites/buttons/etc drawn in Photoshop for my built application.

Would an external C library/framework be able to build a custom GUI when compiling an application?

I've tried to google this question and it seems like nobody cares about design in the scientific community. I'm not quite sure how to phrase my question, apologies. I hope some of you have a bit of experience with this.

P.S.: Below is the look I'd like to achieve:
[image]

Comment: I think you are referring to the IDE itself. You are free to make a MATLAB IDE any way you want, using any language you want. I recommend not using MATLAB in fact. You'd have your work cut out for you though. It would be a huge undertaking.

Comment: @chessofnerd Well, I mean I want MATLAB to compile my application using a custom GUI, and not a windows form or whatever MATLAB has a wrapper of.

Comment: I'm guessing (I don't know) that MATLAB's command line exposes a lot of the functionality you would need. I'm rather certain what you are describing is an IDE.

Comment: Please see edited description, I didn't realize how unclear I was. I don't mean the IDE, I mean the app I'm compiling in MATLAB. I don't like how the app looks.

Comment: Makes more sense now. I would suggest a MVC pattern and a client in another language (my default would be html/JavaScript). Also, in your question you mention your compiled MATLAB application, FYI, MATLAB is interpreted so there is no compilation.

Comment: I may suggest [uihtml](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uihtml.html) so you can create your interface using html/css/javascript ... Passing data between matlab and interface is done via the field `data` of the `uihtml` component using [jsonencode](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html) /  [jsondecode](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html) in the background ... anyhow this still probably is a huge amount of work/debugging/maintenance espcially if you need to insert matlab `axes` and not using web charts

Comment: I would also suggest [mlapptools](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/mlapptools) and reading [customizing uifigures](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/customizing-web-gui-uipanel)for styling things.

Comment: “the skin from the 90s just don't cut it anymore.” Micard obviously doesn’t know what GUIs looked like in the 1990’s! :D

Comment: *"nobody cares about design in the scientific community"* I am not even paid to write the code, how am I supposed to care about the design of it! We scientist care, but really, we don't have the manpower for it.

Answer (score 8):

As described in my previous comment, and **starting from R2019b**, you can use [uihtml](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uihtml.html) components in new web-based [uifigure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uifigure.html) (introduced in R2016a) to customize style of elements appearing on screen via `css` + `javascript`

Here below is a very simple example for a css-styled button:

First the matlab code (`TestUiHtml.m`):

```
function [] = TestUiHtml()
%[
    % Create the figure and layout
    fig = uifigure('Name', 'Test uihtml', 'Color', [1 1 1]);
    grid = uigridlayout('Parent', fig, 'ColumnWidth', { '1x', '1x' }, 'RowHeight', {200, '1x' }, 'BackgroundColor', fig.Color);  
    
    % Add a uihtml element (that will act like a button using html+css+javascript)
    button = uihtml('Parent', grid, 'HTMLSource', 'myway.html', 'DataChangedFcn', @(s,e)onBtnClicked(fig)); 

    % Button layout
    button.Layout.Row = 1; button.Layout.Column = [1 2];    
%]
end
function [] = onBtnClicked(fig)
%[
    uialert(fig, 'World!', 'Clicked', 'Icon', 'info');
%]
end
```

NB: Above code simply adds in the figure a `uihtml` component  whose property `HTMLSource` points to the html content you want to have.

Here is the html code to describe the custom `uihtml` component content (`myway.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myway.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myway.js"></script>
</head>    
<html>
    <body> 
        <div class="container">
          <button class="skewBtn blue" id="btn">Hello!</button>  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

NB: It is not mandatory to have a fully well-formed html code (i.e. just a `<button style="...">Hello</button>` would do).

The linked css code to style the html content (`myway.css`):

```
body { 
    background-color: transparent;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 97vh;
}
.container .skewBtn {
  width: 180px;
  height: 80px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
  font-size: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.container .skewBtn:hover {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.blue {
  border: 2px solid #1976D2;
  color: #1976D2;
}
.blue:hover {
  background-color: #1976D2;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

And finally the javascript code for event/data marshalling between matlab and the html-based component ... or for more advanced programming logic, if any, for the html-content (`myway.js`):

```
function setup(htmlComponent) 
{
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) 
    {
        htmlComponent.Data = 1234; // dummy value to fire event on matlab side
    });
}
```

Marshalling is ensure via the `data` property of a `htmlComponent` object which both sides (i.e. matlab/javascript) are listening to for changes. Matlab automatically uses [jsonencode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsonencode.html)/[jsondecode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html) in the background so you can pass back and forth almost any structure/values you need directly.

And voilà ... a nice-and-responsive css-styled button in matlab's figure:

[image: uihtml button example]

It would be of course better to refactor above code as a `uibuttonex` class modeled on existing [uibutton](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uibutton.html) property name/value pairs.

**Sarting from R2021a** it is eventually possible to add it to app designer library of components as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/custom-ui-component-classes-in-app-designer.html) (I personally don't use the designer and prefer to code interfaces programmatically).

**Some remarks**

It is not possible to directly style exiting `uibutton`, `uipanel`, `uitab`, etc... elements => Mathwork does not allow to access uifigure's html nor to inject css/javascript in it easily (see following undocumented-matlab [thread](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/customizing-web-gui-uipanel) and [mlapptools](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/mlapptools) project to try to cheat things). For instance a `uibutton` does not translate to directly `<button>` markup in uifigure's source but a lot of imbricated `<div>`, so it is very difficult to style (and will probably change from one release to another).

I would not recommend to create a single `uihtml` element in the figure and code everything in html+css+javascript, but I would rather recommend to create small and simple custom `uibuttonex`, etc elements ... else you'll have to deal with a single `data` blob to connect you interface with the matlab code which can be tricky and difficult to reuse.

Unfortunately it is yet not possible to create custom html-containers in which you can add other child ui-elements (custom or non-custom) ... say bye-bye to create containers similar to [uix.GridFlex](http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/matlab_programming_class_2012/guide/GUILayout_v1p10/GUILayout-v1p10/layoutHelp/Function%20reference3_2.html), [uix.CardPanel](http://cda.psych.uiuc.edu/matlab_programming_class_2012/guide/GUILayout_v1p10/GUILayout-v1p10/layoutHelp/Function%20reference1_2.html) from the wonderful GUI Layout toolbox or to creating nicely styled `uitabex`, etc... This is really a missing part !

Looking at source code of `uifigure` pages, custom ui-elements are also embedded in `<iframe></iframe>` markups, so it is not possible to inject some global css/javascript code (i.e. you'll have to repeat this for each `uihtml` element you create). It is not possible (or difficult) then to have multiple uihtml elements to interact with each-other (unless coding everything in a single page or passing through matlab code/events only).

*Addendum* : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743115/iframe-how-to-share-css-file) is a solution to get css-style from parent, unfortunately this does not solve one need to inject this css in the main uifigure source (well this can be done in javascript ... something like `if !exist(parent.elements where id="mycss") => parent.document.inject(lalala)`)

Mathworks is going the good direction with `uifigure` and `html` in the background, but it's still a bit too locked for now and missing important containers from the [GUI Layout toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox).

NB: I tried the GUI Layout toolbox elements in `uifigure` ... some are working (with lot of resizing bugs), other are not working at all (GridFlex). Maybe a new version of the toolbox will come.

**Charting**

For modern charting you can use javascript libraries like [D3js](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery), [SciChart](https://demo.scichart.com/javascript-3d-surface-mesh-chart), [LightningChart](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0909-3dRealtimeLine.html), or others!!.

[image: d3jsexample]

There is some [example using D3](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72866-d3-js-visualizations-in-matlab-app-designer-apps) on fileexchange

Comment: Amazing answer. Seeing as this question was from 2017, I think it would perhaps benefit by adding for which version(s) of Matlab does this work.

Comment: @MatteoV Thanks :) ... I edited my answer to insert information about minimal version (R2016a for `uifigure`, R2019b for `uihtml` and R2021a of adding custom components to the `AppDesigner` library)